# Increase the Y value in excel each time I fill out a form with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form in Excel and I use Vba to collect that data and put it in a table. Each time I fill in new information, all it does is to replace the old. That is because outout from Visual Basic is not dynamic. 
My question is how I increase the Y axis each time I fill out the form. I need a variable in the Range/Cells that increase with 1 each time I press the macro button.

```
Sub aksjer()

Dim stockname As String
Dim price As Integer
Dim number As Integer
Dim totalprice As Integer
Dim pe As Integer
Dim mkt As Long
Dim volume As Integer
Dim eps As Integer
Dim divye As Integer

stockname = Range("M5").Value
price = Range("M6").Value
number = Range("M7").Value
totalprice = Range("M8").Value
mkt = Range("M9").Value
pe = Range("M10").Value
eps = Range("M11").Value
divye = Range("M12").Value
volume = Range("M13").Value

Range("A6") = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
Range("B6") = stockname
Range("C6") = price
Range("D6") = number
Range("E6") = totalprice
Range("G6") = pe
Range("F6") = mkt
Range("J6") = volume
Range("H6") = eps
Range("I6") = divye

Range("M5:M13") = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to pass your values into a variable and then pass them back into a cell.  Waste of code.  Try this:

```
Sub aksjer()

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Range("M5").Value
Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Range("M6").Value
Range("D" & LastRow).Value = Range("M7").Value
Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Range("M8").Value
Range("F" & LastRow).Value = Range("M9").Value
Range("G" & LastRow).Value = Range("M10").Value
Range("H" & LastRow).Value = Range("M11").Value
Range("I" & LastRow).Value = Range("M12").Value
Range("J" & LastRow).Value = Range("M13").Value

Range("M5:M13").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check for how many rows are already used with this

```
usedrows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.End(xlDown).Row
```

Then refer to your your cells as `Cells` not `Range` with +1 for row number example using your date:

```
Cells( usedrows + 1 , 1) = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Comment: If you like Range references you could just increment that as well with Range.("A" & 1 + usedrows)

Comment: When I fill inone more company the old information is getting replaced. I need the new information to stack under the previous

Comment: I understand that and my method will check how much information have you already entered, and it will enter new information one row bellow.